# Distributivity of intersection over addition in ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I have been trying to read ring theory on my own, from Dummit and Foote, and this question has been on my mind for a while:

Let $I,J,K$ be ideals of a ring $R$ (may be non commutative, but has a $1$). Can we say the following:
$$I \cap (J + K) = I \cap J + I \cap K\ ?$$

I get that the RHS is a subset of the LHS, but I am not able to say anything about the other inclusion. Maybe someone can provide a counterexample?

Also, what about the case when $R$ does not have a $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.  I find this ring interesting because its lattice of proper ideals is precisely the [diamond lattice $M_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties).

Let $I=(x)$, $J=(y)$, $K=(x+y)$.  Then $I\cap J$ and $I\cap K$ are both zero, but $I\cap (J+K)=I$.

> *Also, what about the case when  does not have a 1?*

If you *really* want an example like that, just pick your favorite ring without identity $S$, and use $R$ above and find the counterexample embedded in $R\times S$.

Rings which satisfy that property on right ideals are called *right distributive*, but I do not know if anyone has studied the definition that is restricted to two-sided ideals.

Comment: [DaRT query for non right-distributive ring examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?L=104r)