# Distributive property of sum and intersection of ideals in a polynomial ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, binary-operations, polynomial-rings

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field, and $I,J,K$ be three ideals of $S$.
Are the following right or are they wrong?

1. $ I+ (J\cap K)=(I+J)\cap (I+ K)$
2. $ I\cap (J+ K)=(I\cap J)+ (I\cap K)$

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rings in which 1 holds for all $I,J,K$ - or equivalently, those in which 2 holds for all $I,J,K$ - are called *arithmetical*. In a non-arithmetical ring, 1 and 2 would hold only in the special case where $I$ contains at least one of $J$ or $K$: see e.g. [When does the distributive law apply to ideals in a commutative ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/when-does-the-distributive-law-apply-to-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring) and [Distributivity of intersection over addition in ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433641/distributivity-of-intersection-over-addition-in-ideals).

A domain (i.e. a ring where products of non-zero elements are non-zero) that happens to be an arithmetical ring is called a *Prüfer domain*. As the answers linked above also explain, there are a number of natural conditions under which a domain will be Prüfer - for example, $D$ is Prüfer if and only if Gauss's lemma holds in $D$; or $D$ is Prüfer if and only if the Chinese remainder theorem holds in $D$. Thus 1 and 2 **do** hold in general in e.g. any principal ideal domain: see [Distributive law of ideals in $\mathbf Z$ relating $\cap$ & $+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311338/distributive-law-of-ideals-in-mathbf-z-relating-cap).

But by contrast, it turns out that **multivariate** polynomial domains are **never** Prüfer! See [When do (multivariate) polynomial rings fail to be Prüfer rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250939/when-do-multivariate-polynomial-rings-fail-to-be-pr%C3%BCfer-rings). So the answer to your particular problem is that 1 and 2 don't hold except (as mentioned above) if $I \supset J$ or $I \supset K$.